# How to add a loading.. message in the AJAX call?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I have a AJAX function like this:

```
function change_session(val) {
    var change_session_id=document.getElementById('select_path').value;
      $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "/change_path/",
                async: false,
                data: {change_session_id:change_session_id},
                success: function(data){
                    document.getElementById('transfer1').innerHTML=data;
                    document.getElementById('transfer1').style.display="block";
                }
            });

}
```

I am applying AJAX in a select statement:

```
<select onchange="change_session()" name="select_path" id="select_path">

              <option name="server_id" id="select_path" value="{{ i.id }}">{{ active }}</option>
              {% for i in session_info %}
              <option name="server_id" id="select_path" value="{{ i.id }}">{{ i.session_name }}</option>
               {% endfor %}
               <input type="hidden" id="change_session_id" value="{{ i.id }}" />
            </select>
```

Everything is working fine but while changing the `option` in the select statement the content takes a time to load and the option statement freezes until the function change_path is completed. So I want to add the message `"Loading"`in the div element while the loading completes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should remove the `async:false` which freezes the window. Then before you 
make the AJAX call you display the loading message in the dom, and hide it on success:

```
function change_session(val) {
var change_session_id=document.getElementById('select_path').value;

$("#transfer1").html("Loading...");

  $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/change_path/",
            data: {change_session_id:change_session_id},
            success: function(data){

                $('#transfer1').html(data)
                    .css("display", "block");

            }
        });

 }
```

And when already are using jQuery you could use jQuery selectors/functions instead of plain JavaScript. :)

Comment: I am completely new with jQuery, Ajax and Javascript too. Your solution works completely fine but there are already some contents which I want to replace with Loading when user selects the drop down menu. How can I do that?

Comment: I have updated the code to use jQuery and changed the loading-icon to be the `#transfer1` element. Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: If I want to pass a variable rather than hardcoded text (Loading...) then how to achieve that. Suppose var x = "loading..." and then I want to pass x as message. Please help.

Comment: .html(x) instead og .html("loading...")

Answer (score 7):

You must change `async:false` to `async:true` because making it `false` is no more an asynchronous request.

You can use the callback methods of JQuery to do something before sending the AJAX request in `beforeSend` block and after the completion you can use `complete` callback to hide the loading message.

```
function change_session(val) {
    var change_session_id=document.getElementById('select_path').value;
      $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "/change_path/",
                async: false,
                data: {change_session_id:change_session_id},
                beforeSend: function ( xhr ) {    
                     $("#loadingDIV").show();
                },
                success: function(data){
                    document.getElementById('transfer1').innerHTML=data;
                    document.getElementById('transfer1').style.display="block";
                },
                complete : $("#loadingDIV").hide()
            });

}
```

Answer (score 1):

jQuery has some events built in for this.

```
/**
 * onAjax -> Loading indicator 
 */
$("body").on({
    ajaxStart: function() { 
        $(this).addClass("loading"); // I mostly use this. It adds a class to the body.
    },
    ajaxStop: function() { 
        $(this).removeClass("loading"); 
    }    
});
```

So in the css you could do something like:

```
#loading-ind {position:absolute; top:0; left:0; height:100%; width:100%; display:none;}
body.loading #loading-ind {display:block;}
```

These CSS rules are just an example, the important property is display. The rest you can set to whatever you like.

You can however do all kind of things instead of removing/adding a class ;)
In your case it would be adding the 'loading..' text to the div. Keep in mind these events fire on ALL ajax calls, so don't know if that's the best option.

Comment: How to make the text dynamic. I mean suppose I have a var x= "loading" and I want to pass x instead of "loading" how to go about it. Please help.

Comment: $(document).on worked for me. $("body"). not worked .

Answer (score 1):

**css code :**

```
.loadingMask {  
    background: url(loader.gif) center 50% no-repeat #000000; 
    top:0; 
    left:0; 
    position:fixed; 
    height:100%; 
    width:100%; 
    opacity:0.7;
    filter:alpha(opacity=70); 
    z-index:12030   
 }
```

this `css` will generate an loading overlay to your web page..

in background property 
give any loading image path.. you can generate your Loading images with the [ajaxload.info Generator](http://www.ajaxload.info/).

**HTML :**

```
<div class="loadingMask" id="loadingMask" style="visibility: hidden;"></div>
```

**JavaScript :**

```
function change_session(val) {
    var change_session_id=document.getElementById('select_path').value;
      $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "/change_path/",
                async: false,
                beforeSend :function(){
                    $("#loadingMask").css('visibility', 'visible');
                },
                data: {change_session_id:change_session_id},
                success: function(data){
                    $("#loadingMask").css('visibility', 'hidden');
                    document.getElementById('transfer1').innerHTML=data;
                    document.getElementById('transfer1').style.display="block";
                }
            });

}
```

Answer (score 1):

One workaround is to add a [Bootstrap Tooltip](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tooltips) to any DOM elements which will invoke the *change_session(val)*, with a message about (potential) loading time if clicked.

It's not the best, but if you assume your user is close to clicking on the entry and therefore hovering over it, then you know the message will display.